# WebSocket connection to 'wss://hostname' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: websocket, ratchet

I m trying to run rachet web sockets on live server and getting the following error

WebSocket connection to 'wss://hostname' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

On local server all runs fine

Anyone got any idea what this is ?

Comment: The URL you are trying to connect your WebSocket to does not implement the WebSocket protocol. It is sending back a normal HTTP `200` reply instead of the required `101` reply.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, Inquired about it from my hosting provider they don't support WebSockets on their server. Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: WebSockets requires server support. If your provider doesn't support it, you will have to find another provider that does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks mate

Comment: i think you need to provide more details about your problem. Recently i encountered similar issue in Spring Boot, and the following link helps me. Maybe you have the same problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845452/websocket-handshake-unexpected-response-code-200-angularjs-and-spring-boot